# Sum form value and show it

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

i want to sum value that selected in ckeckbox on the html form by javascript
See the following example :

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="digit_1">
<input type="checkbox" id="digit_2">
<input type="checkbox" id="digit_3">
<input type="checkbox" id="digit_4">

<div id="result"></div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

so i want to give the checkbox values ​​in javascript like the following figure:

```
digit_1 = 10
digit_2 = 5
digit_3 = 1
digit_4 = 20
```

And for example when "digit_1" and "digit_3" selected , it show sum of it (11) in the result div
And when "digit_3" has Removed = 11 - 1 = 10 
show the 10 number in the div

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't putting the values in the HTML?

Comment: no .. Send the result value doesn't matter ... i just want to show sum of digit in the result div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can store the values of the checkboxes on the checkboxes them selves:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="digit_1" value="10">
    <input type="checkbox" id="digit_2" value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" id="digit_3" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="digit_4" value="20">

    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in your script, you can loop through each one and sum up the values:

```
var value;
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("digit_" + i);
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        value += +checkbox.value;
    }
}
result.innerText = value;
```

Your answer will display in the `<div>`.

Comment: you should add a change function to those inputs

Comment: Actually, result was defined in the HTML DOM.

Comment: I would high discourage looping through the values like that.

Comment: I would highly discourage writing elements with id="digit_1", but that's not the question.

Comment: @alancnet Then you might want to avoid giving an answer that binds him to such bad practices

Comment: This is the second time you have criticized my attempts to help people, @AndréSnedeHansen, the first being [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19827231/revisions). Your comments are not constructive. Please keep them to yourself.

Comment: @alancnet Must be coincidence, and not done on purpose :) - Also I don't critize you, I constructively criticize the code. Which is far from best practice, or a solution any viewer, should think is a proper answer to the question. My constructive criticism, is that this kind of solutions should be avoided, as it has far reaching implications on a larger scale.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48503/discussion-between-alancnet-and-andre-snede-hansen)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="summable" id="digit_1" data-value="10">
    <input type="checkbox" class="summable" id="digit_2" data-value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" class="summable" id="digit_3" data-value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="summable" id="digit_4" data-value="20">
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

And JS:

```
function updateSum(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('form input.summable:checked').each(function(){
        sum+=parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'),10);
    });
    $('#result').html('Sum: ' + sum);
}

updateSum();

$(document).on('change', 'input.summable', updateSum);
```

And a JSFiddle to show it off: **http://jsfiddle.net/cxh8s/**

Comment: @user2737385 The JSFiddle is not working? Or when you paste it, into your code? If its your codebase thats the problem, then check if you got jquery.